# Making Children decide the size of parent Div

Tags: html, css

I have a divider and i want it to be minimal height of 126px but when i make content appear in it with javascript i want it to expand with the content... (because i have a boarder around the parent div i actually need it to change size not just show the inside content)

this should be pretty easy but i cant get it to work
any suggestions ??

I added min-height:126px; 
to the style of the div

however when i add new elements i have it being the same size and scroll-bars appear on the sides rather than the element actually increasing in size like i would want it too

here is my css (sry for the mess i will make classes l8ter ):

```
#login {
    position:absolute;
    left:661px;
    top:130px;
    width:162px;
    min-height:126px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

 #username {
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:5px;
    width:144px;
    height:17px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#usernameInput {
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:23px;
    width:101px;
    height:17px;
}
#password {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:40px;
    width:101px;
    height:17px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
#passwordInput {
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:59px;
    width:101px;
    height:17px;
}
#signUp {
    position:absolute;
    left:741px;
    top:108px;
    width:83px;
    height:14px;
}
#loginBttn {
    position:relative;
    left:71px;

    width:37px;
    height:16px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#CreateAcc {
    position:relative;
    left:12px;
    width:119px;
    height:18px;
    z-index:1;
}
#createAccText {
    position:absolute; /*fix positioning so it looks good in browsers probably use float or something similar */
    left:20px;
    top:4px;
    width:88px;
    height:11px;
    z-index:2;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
}

#optional {
    position:absolute;
    left:75px;
    top:8px;
    width:70px;
    height:14px;
    z-index:1;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999;
    display: none;  
}
#relativeHolder {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:77px;
    width:162px;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1;
}
#email {
    position:relative;
    left:12px;
    top:-2px;
    width:101px;
    height:17px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    display:none;

}
#emailIn {
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    width:101px;
    height:17px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    display:none;
}
```

And my html  inside the body tag :

```
<div id="login">

<div id="username">Username</div> <div id="optional">(Optional)</div>
<form name="loginForm">
<div id="usernameInput">
<input name="username" type="text" size="20" value="">
</div>
<div id="password">Password</div>
<div id="passwordInput">
<input name="password" type="password" size="20" value="">
</div>
<div id="relativeHolder"> 

<div id="email">Email</div>
<div id="emailIn"><input name="email" type="text" size="20" value=""></div>


<div id="CreateAcc"> 
 <input name='newAcc' type='checkbox' value='newAcc' onClick='signUp()'  >
<div id="createAccText">Create new Account</div>
</div>

<div id="loginBttn" onclick="login()">Login</div>
</div>
</form>

</div>

<div id="signUp" ></div>
```

javascript:

there is nothing wrong with the js so i dont think i need to post it here
all it does is it changes the display style of emailIn div to inline from hidden.

Comment: Why not have the JS change the size of the divider when the content is added?

Comment: We may need to see more of your CSS as I suspect you may have an overflow property set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvtfS/1/

It uses `min-width` and `min-height`

**EDIT:**

So it seems you are using a lot of `absolute` positioning, which should be avoided.

You should restructure your code along the lines of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/PzF4Z/

```
<form id="login">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text"  />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" />
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>Create new Account</label>
    </div>
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: do you know why scroll-bars appear on the side of my divider ?

Comment: @Xitcod13 you need to set the `overflow` property to either `visible` or `hidden` to get rid of them.

Comment: overflow hidden makes the content added not appear and overflow visible makes it appear but the parent divider does not increase in size it still stays 126px

Comment: @Xitcod13 did you remove the `width:126px` and just use `min-width:126px`?

Comment: i edited my question to contain much more information. I also edited it so I have min-width:162px instead of width:162px; but it didnt work.

Comment: @Xitcod13 the problem is you are using `absolute` positioning

Comment: changing the position to relative of all the div did not help the parent divider to expand it only messed up the layout.

Comment: it would make my code cleaner. however it does not solve my primary problem of expanding the parent element with content. I also have a reason for using so many divs i want to be able to control the position of those divs because its only a mockup and i want the label for password and username be above the input not on the side.

Comment: @Xitcod13, it does solve your problem, because the wrapper will expand to fit the content. And Its fine to make the make the content sit how ever you want, just don't do it with `position: absolute`, because if you use `position: absolute` then those element have no `width` or `height`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10768/discussion-between-petah-and-xitcod13)

Answer (score 1):

Set a minimum width or height on the parent `<div>`

```
min-width:126px;
```

Comment: By default a `div` is `width: 100%`, is it not?

Comment: thanks but i want to get rid of the scrollbars that appear on the side of my divider :(

Comment: Yes that is correct, I'll adjust my answer to specify that a min width or height should be set on the parent.

Comment: @Petah: No, it's `width: auto`, which is very different from `width: 100%`.

Comment: add overflow:hidden to remove scroll bars

Comment: @luke2012 adding overflow:hidden removes the scroll bars but it also makes the new content invisible (as its below the height of the parent div)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='min-width:100px; width:100px;'>
     <!-- the content -->
</div>
```

This would expand, as content is added. based on the parent - nope?

Comment: would you know how to get rid of the scrollbars that appear on the side of my parent div when i add content inside ??