# Make Parent DIV the width of its children

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a parent div the width of the child elements within it without setting a fixed width. However, sofar I have no luck.

The element I need sized sits within a 'content container' which has no width defined and thus is the width of the page.

I have put it into a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8LfsW/) and the 'content-container' has a width set so as to emulate it being viewed on a larger screen. You will see that the 'mag-details' container is rather larger than the content within it.

The .content-main style used live is:

```
.content-container{
    font-family:"helvetica neue",helvetica,arial;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

and the mag details style

```
#mag-details{
    margin:auto;
    background:#FCFCFC;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius:8px;
    max-width:1200px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #CCCCCC;
}
```

If someone could advise me how and if possible to size the mag-details container to the size of the content within it that would be much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try making `#mag-details` use `display:inline-block`

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406268/making-children-decide-the-size-of-parent-div).

Answer (score 2):

Change the parent to

```
display: inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HT46H/

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. `float:left`. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LfsW/2/)**
2. `display: inline-block`. **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/83Qay/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the floats and use `inline-block` on those elements.

Then use `white-spane:nowrap` on the wrapping element so they do not break when screen is too small..

So add

```
min-width:100%;
display:inline-block;
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the `#mag-details` and change the `li` elements to `display:inline-block`

Result at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/54kjf/